# Codeigniter 3 authentication: can't echo variable from session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am working on a *Codeigniter 3 authentication application*. I am new to CI, so I am run into this elementary problem: being unable to store/output a variable from the session (I need his to display the **signed in user's data**).

The **User model**:

```
class Usermodel extends CI_Model {
    public function user_login($email, $password)
    {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));
            return $query->row();
    }
}
```

The **Signin controller** looks like this:

```
class Signin extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
      $this->load->view('signin');
  }

  public function signin()
  {  
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
      if ($this->form_validation->run())
      {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
          $this->load->model('Usermodel');
          $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
          if ($current_user) {
              $current_user_id = $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $current_user->id);
              $current_user_email = $this->session->set_userdata('email', $current_user->email);
              // Echo from database
              echo $current_user->id . " | " . $current_user->email;

              //Echo from session
              echo $current_user_id . " | " . $current_user_email;
          } else {
            redirect('signin'); 
          }
      }
      else
      {
        $this->load->view('signin');
      }
  }
}
```

I was able, in the controller, to print out the signed in user id and email address from the database with this line `echo $current_user->id . " | " . $current_user->email;`. The browser shows: `1 | razvan_zamfir80@yahoo.com`.

But I can't do he same from the session: `echo $current_user_id . " | " . $current_user_email;` outputs nothing.

Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Explained here getting session data  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data and setting https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it (from the CI user guide):

```
$current_user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id', $current_user->id);
$current_user_email = $this->session->userdata('email', $current_user->email);
```

instead of

```
$current_user_id = $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $current_user->id);
$current_user_email = $this->session->set_userdata('email', $current_user->email);
```

Comment: 1. `set_userdata` does not return anything so setting a variable from its return is nonsense. 2. The vars you set (`$current_user_id` and  `$current_user_email`) would not be used anyway because you immediately `redirect`. 3. In Codeigniter 3 the recommended way to SET session data is directly to the `$_SESSION` super global, i.e. `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $current_user->id;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
$user_data = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

Because (`void`)

```
$this->session->set_userdata(...)
```

Returns nothing.

- `void` - function does not provide a result value to its caller.

Ref: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L768

```
/**
 * Set userdata
 *
 * Legacy CI_Session compatibility method
 *
 * @param   mixed   $data   Session data key or an associative array
 * @param   mixed   $value  Value to store
 * @return  void
 */
public function set_userdata($data, $value = NULL){

}
```

Comment: What about a gogout function? How do I destroy a session in CI3?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir: `$this->session->sess_destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced such problems but I recommend  you to use an existing library like tank-auth, or ion-auth or any other it will save you time on project except if you are doing it for learning purpose.

Comment: I have tried Ion-auth. but I did not find any useful tutorial on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

session data will not be available as soon you set it. it is available in next redirect. if you want to check if the session is present or not, set the session then redirect to another controller and check the session variables there.

sessions are not meant to work like how you have tried above.can u care to tell us why you are doing so.